# MyEclipse Tomcat server is not responding when i start my application

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, myeclipse

i have deployed my applicaton in MyEclipse Tomcat server i configured apache-tomcat 7.0.8 in my local with jdk 1.6. After starting the server successfully i tried to enter the localhost url in the addressbar. But no response i got. i tried as

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb
```

But it is saying as "HTTP 400 Bad Request". i had redeployed the application and tried again by restarting the server.

After starting my server the console is having

```
2012-09-27 12:33:52,924 INFO  main             org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin  - Tiles definition factory loaded for module '/cash'.
2012-09-27 12:33:52,987 INFO  main             org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin  - Tiles definition factory loaded for module '/csv'.
2012-09-27 12:33:53,268 INFO  main             org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin  - Tiles definition factory loaded for module '/cases'.
Sep 27, 2012 12:33:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 27, 2012 12:33:53 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 27, 2012 12:33:53 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/31  config=null
Sep 27, 2012 12:33:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10077 ms
```

When i entered the url in browser i didn't find any logs in console.
Any sugessions, highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the log say?  Also, the server *is* responding.. with a 400.  There's a very big difference between that and your browser eventually saying "request timed out".

Comment: check using tomcat manager application wheather your project myweb is in running state ?

Comment: Are you deploying this to the Tomcat service? or running Tomcat from Eclipse?

Comment: Check that you can start Tomcat outside of MyEclipse and get to the home page, localhost:8080, from a browser, just to see if there is something about the way MyEclipse is starting it or whether the problem is in how you've set up the Tomcat installation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect to your Tomcat server homepage by giving the below link

```
http://localhost:8080
```

?

Comment: No. it is Saying same as "HTTP 400 Bad Request".

Comment: Then there is some problem with the Tomcat service or either you may be connecting to a different port.
Are you running tomcat as a service?

Comment: i am connecting with 8080. yes i am running tomcat as a service.

Comment: @Arun If the default ROOT folder doesn't exist the OP won't see the Tomcat server homepage. So not always the case to just hit that URL and check for the Tomcat Page